# Infinite video stream with java and video.js

Tags: javascript, java, video, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I'm trying to figure out how to provide an endless video stream using Java and video.js. So on the backend side, I hold a playlist of one `.m3u8` file and couple `.ts` files. And my flow consists of the following steps:

1. Give `.m3u8` text on UI. [.m3u8 endpoint screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9XRG.png)
2. Start the flow on the front-end side by video.js lib. [video.js part screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH9l5.png)
3. Video.js requests for a single `.ts` file that was indicated in `.m3u8` file. [ts endpoint screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTPuN.png)
4. On the backend with the help of a sheduler, I change the context state `streamContentContext.setCurrentChunkId(streamContentContext.getCurrentChunkId() + 1)`, and when video.js realizes that the only ts file is over, he tries to update `.m3u8` file. At this moment, the index of ts is already updated by the scheduler and it should request `/ts/2` endpoint.

THE PROBLEM IS: all subsequent `.ts` files on the front-end side simply cannot be played, maybe there should be some kind of attribute or event that will start adding a new piece of video to the previous one.

UPD: after I read this article (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/example_playlists_for_http_live_streaming/live_playlist_sliding_window_construction) it all became clear to me that it’s worth removing some attributes from `.m3u8` file, so I left only `#EXTM3U, #EXT-X-VERSION:3, #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11, #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE: + streamContentContext.getCurrentChunkId()`

[browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PyNm.png)

Comment: How are you generating the ts files? Are the timestamps continuous?

Comment: Yes, there are ordered .ts list generated by ffmpeg